# CocoaPods and CI

Tags: unit-testing, continuous-integration, cocoapods

I've got a number of unit tests set up for testing an object. The unit tests rely on OCMock, Specta and Expecta and I'm pulling in these three libraries with Cocoapods.

The problem I'm having is running this on a remote CI machine. Using xctool to build-tests does not seem to properly build required libraries and I'm unclear whether I can actually use xcodebuild for command line unit testing. This means the required pods libraries never get generated from command line.

Locally where I've done a pod install, opened up the workspace and had Xcode auto-generate schemes for each target, including those in the Pods project, I can have my build script manually build the required Pods library with the proper scheme. However on the remote machine this scheme doesn't exist.

An obvious solution is to include the root Pods/ folder, this would include the project files and the schemes (if I mark them as shared). I'd prefer to avoid this.

For specificity I am interested in how to accomplish this with Jenkins and with Travis

Comment: What CI system are you using? There are different approaches for each one (Jenkins, Travis, Bots etc)

Comment: I'd love to hear why there are different approaches for each, my expectation would be that they should build almost identically. I edited the question to include the CI systems.

Comment: Can't you just run a pod install as a pre-build step on your CI system before running the CI Job?

Comment: @cschuff Thanks for the suggestion! It's been so long, I don't remember the context. I think this may have been more along the lines of how Cocoapods builds the workspace and how that relates to xcodebuild and xctool's test processes. I'm going to delete the question because I don't recall and it doesn't seem useful anymore